await asyncio.to_thread blocks complete event loop?
I am trying to create a Python program that - when triggered via a websocket - does some blocking work in a thread. I would expect my program to be able to continue to react to the stop signal also received via websocket, but it does not.
It works when I change from result = await blocking to task = asyncio.create_task(blocking), but I don't understand why it does not work with result = await blocking. Can someone please explain that? Thanks!
import asyncio
import json
import websockets


class MweThreading:
    def __init__(self):
        self.continue_blocking_work = False

    def do_blocking_work(self):
        print("do_blocking_work was called")

        while self.continue_blocking_work:
            print("doing blocking work ...")

        print("Ended blocking work (after while loop)")


    async def handle_websocket(self,websocket):
        async for message in websocket:
            payload = json.loads(message)

            if payload["action"] == "start_blocking_work":
                print("handle websocket action start_blocking_work")
                self.continue_blocking_work = True

                blocking = asyncio.to_thread(self.do_blocking_work)

                # this does not work - BUT WHY? <=========================================
                result = await blocking

                # this works
                # task = asyncio.create_task(blocking)

                print("after blocking")

            elif payload["action"] == "stop_blocking_work":
                print("handle websocket action stop_blocking_work")
                self.continue_blocking_work = False

            else:
                raise Exception("error handling JSON payload")


    async def main(self):
        async with websockets.serve(self.handle_websocket, "localhost", 8765):
            print("Websocket server started on ws://localhost:8765")
            await asyncio.Future()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mwe = MweThreading()
    asyncio.run(mwe.main())


You are purposely stopping with an await in the middle of the loop. That will prevent your code from receiving any other message until your await completes.

"does not work" -- it works perfectly. Moving the current coroutine into the wait list until the awaited coroutine completes is exactly what await is supposed to do.

doesn't await return control to the event loop, so the next web socket message should be processed? (obviously it does not, can someone explain in more details for me?)

await returns control to the event loop that schedules coroutines. That's not the same as returning control to your event loop (implemented as a coroutine itself).

If you were using anyio instead of upstream asyncio, I'd point you to TaskGroup.start_soon. In upstream asyncio, you probably want an asyncio.Task. Still applies that you don't await a task until you're ready to block.

(we're outside the edit window, but read my prior comment to say "returns control to the internal-to-asyncio event loop that schedules coroutines", if those extra words help to make it clearer).
